# React Native - Application crashes after running and applying "setInterval"

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, setinterval

I'm here to ask a problem that I couldn't resolve for a day.

After applying **setInterval**, my application crashes on physical android phone and in my emulator it shows an error that I'm not familiar.

In physical android phone and emulator, after I log in in application and **STAY** for a minute in a particular page/screen it will crash or show an error.

Here's my code

```
export default class tables extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            ....
        }
    }
    fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://192.168.254.***:****/table');
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ data: json });
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.Set_int = setInterval(() => {
            this.fetchData().then(() => {
                this.setState({ isLoading: false })
            });
        }, 5000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        clearInterval(this.Set_int);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                 ....
                 .......
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

[image]

My console.log:

[image]

Comment: `componentDidMount` can be a regular method on the class, no need have it be a class field arrow function, `componentDidMount()`. Same for `componentWillUnmount`, but you want to use `componentDidUnmount` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`2693896` in server log likely refers to response length, and 2.6 Mb JSON response that is parsed to an object can occupy a plenty of RAM. The data is requested each 5 seconds, regardless of whether the previous request was completed. If a client or a server can't process data at that speed, requests and state updates will accumulate and occupy all available RAM.

`setInterval` shouldn't be generally used with promises because it ignores promise chain.

In order to improve this situation, a new interval should be either scheduled only when state update is completed, or in case 5s intervals should be preserved, the requests could be cancelled with [abortable fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort).